# react-native-element-dropdown how to add borderRadius for item selected in container list

Tags: react-native

How I can specify borderRadius for item selected in container list.

Github react-native-element-dropdown package used: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-element-dropdown

Answer (score 1):

I know it's too late, nevertheless, somebody might stumble upon this question.

From my understanding it looks like there's no option to add `borderRadius` to each item.

**Solution:** just add `overflow: hidden` to the `<Dropdown/>` like so:

```
<Dropdown
  containerStyle={{
    overflow: 'hidden', // <- here
    borderRadius: 30, // <- for instance
  }}
 ...
/>
```